# VS2005: when stepping through C# code, is there way to skip through sections of code?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2005

What can be done to skip through the parts of code when stepping through code?  I find this particularly annoying when the debugger jumps to property gets and sets.  Is there way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a step over (F10) function, as well as a step into (F11).

Comment: And also Step Out (ctrl-F11) (continue until you have returned to the immediate calling function).

Answer (score 9):

If you want to skip an entire method you can mark it with the [`DebuggerStepThrough`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public void SomeMethod()
{
    // lots of code...
}

public int SomeProperty
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough] 
    get { return ComplexLogicConvertedToMethod(); } 
    [DebuggerStepThrough]      
    set { this.quantity = value ; }
}
```

Note that the attribute prevents the debugger from stepping into the method or property, but you can always place a breakpoint in that method and stop there<sup>1</sup>.

The attribute comes in handy especially when you have code like this:

```
DoSomething(obj.SomeProperty);
```

If you want to step into `DoSomething` and press F11 you will - without the attribute - first step into `SomeProperty` and then into `DoSomething`. With the attribute however, you end up immediately in the `DoSomething` method.

<sup>1</sup><sub>If you want to completely prevent users from placing a breakpoint into a method you can use the [`DebuggerHiddenAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute.aspx).</sub>

Comment: Not awarded because did not mention F10.

Comment: And that's what you get for presuming that the question was less naive than it really was.

Answer (score 5):

there's an option `Step over properties and operators (Managed only)`

or use F10 instead of F11 (with default keyboard binding)

Comment: That option is not available in VS2005.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "run to cursor" for one time breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

When you used F10 the code simply steps over each statement unless you've set a break point in a deeper level. I've never found the debugger miss behave the way you've suggested , mind you I'm only using VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attribute [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) on any methods/properties you don't want to step into.

And you can also use the "Step Over" rather than "Step Into" command.

Answer (score 0):

Add **DebuggerStepThrough** attribute to your property:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
private static void DO() {
  Console.WriteLine("test");
}
```